Query length in Custom Search API
I'm sending requests to Custom Search API like this:
GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL=f'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={GOOGLE_SEARCH_API_KEY}&cx={SEARCH_ENGINE_ID}&q={encoded_text}'

The text in encoded_text could be very large sometimes, and I received a 413 error.
What is the length limit for this parameter?

Can you add more context? if you can, please, provide a example code. Maybe is the library, the header request or something like that

From the documentation, the limit on the length of the Custom Search API request should be within 2048 characters.
